# apache 2.4 access denied compat

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm recently upgraded from 2.2 to 2.4 and I'm having trouble with access denied on a vhost. The error log is

```
[access_compat:error] [pid 27948] [client 1.2.3.4:5] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/mysite
```

Now in my `apache2.conf` I currently have

```
<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And in my vhost file I have

```
<Directory /var/www/mysite>
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But accessing my site gives the access denied error.

in my vhost config's `<Directory>` section.

I need the auth compat module for now because of lots of `.htaccess` files relying on it, but I don't see why it's needed at the server config level when I'm properly using the newer `Require all` syntax?

### What works

If I put the following in my vhost's Directory section, it works.

```
Order deny,allow
```

Take it away (leaving the Required all granted) and it fails again. Its like the compat module is defaulting to `Order allow,deny` but there is no such statement as far as I can see (not in `apache.conf`, not in `conf-enabled/*`, not in `sites-enabled/*default*`).

The Apache docs do not state how the compat and newer authz modules work together (there's a comment on their site point this out). I have implemented the change on 6 other servers without a problem. I've dealt with the ensuring .conf is at the end of the configuration files. I've run apache2ctl configtest, I've run apache2ctl -S to look at the vhosts config; all good.

**Why is the old compat Order statement required? / Why is the compat stuff apparently overriding the newer config?**

Comment: check this out : https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ClientDeniedByServerConfiguration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not Apache's fault (as if it ever were going to be!). I found that one of my vhosts included an `Order allow,deny` statement in the root directory, and that this snippet had somehow been put outside the closing `</VirtualHost>` element.

Because Apache sources all enabled vhosts into a single file, this was the equivalent of putting it at the top, global level. Only by switching on and off vhosts one by one did I find the problem.

Hopefully this question highlights a useful gotcha for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You did not write the name of the vhost file. In apache 2.4 it must have the suffix .conf

Otherwise run through the check-list here.

[Updating Virtual Host Settings from Apache 2.2 to Apache 2.4](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/upgrading/updating-virtual-host-settings-from-apache-2-2-to-apache-2-4)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but yeah, that's fine, all my conf files end `.conf`.

Comment: OK, fine. There is one more thing I dont understand: How come it works with "Order deny,allow" and apache 2.4? It should not be possible. There could be a symlink which points to another directory in /etc/ .

Comment: The old Order stanzas are supported via the auth compat module. This is important for support in old .htaccess files